# copy paste shortcuts not working for ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I tried rebooting ubuntu couple of times but the shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is not working in any workspace or browser to do basic copy paste action. Not even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> is working in terminal. Is this the recurring bug from previous version. does we have solution at hand ?

Comment: Are you switching keyboard layouts with `<Ctrl+Shift>`? What is your current desktop? How many keyboard layouts do you have?

Comment: No I have not switched layouts, I have just upgraded from 16.10 to 18.04.1 LTS. I didn't have this problem in previous version. I have dual boot on dell laptop with default english keypad as settings.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently this worked,

When I enter settings->device->keyboard ,then reset all shortcut-key. All default shortcut key works normally including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work for me. There is just one shortcut that is not working (Shift+Insert) because at some point I've tried to assign it to some other custom shortcut. Default behaviour does not restore after a reset unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance: have you enabled "pointer location" in google-tweaks? This was the culprit for me. Disabling this feature that highlights the pointer when Ctrl key is pressed solved the problem for me.